# android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid user authentication validity duration

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I am facing a weird issue while consuming android keystore in my app.

Only happening on **Mi devices (Tried with Mi A1 and Redmi Note 4 models).**

This is how I am generating the key to be stored in androidkeystore:

```
final SecretKey secretKey;
        final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("alias",
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
            .build();
        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Now while consuming it, if I keep using the key multiple times repeatedly after intervals of 1 sec,

the following Runtime Exception is seen intermittently:

```
android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid user authentication validity duration
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:692)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:777) 
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54) 
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89) 
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265) 
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:148) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2659) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2556) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2475) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:566) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:973) 
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:908)
```

IMO, it seems like a bug with Mi provider.

Any help/workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried if this line `.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5)` can affect this behavior? You should try to extend this value

Comment: yeah, if I set it to `1800`, it works fine. But I still don't know why it's failing at `5`. So I am not confident of pushing `1800` also.

Comment: Maybe 1800 is too high. Is working with 10 or 20? The problem could be caused by a slow implementation